element 'nav' not supported in Visual Studio 2008
I am using Visual Studio 2008. My system dosen't support element 'nav' when I writing asp.net code. Please help me?
My code :
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 5.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        
        <div>        
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            </nav>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>


"I am using Visual Studio 2008" Why?

You HTML also has an extra </div> within the <nav> element that probably isn't helping matters.

extra  was by mistake.  My visual studio shows "Validation(xhtml 1.0 transitional): element 'nav' is not supported"

The death of XHTML was signed off when HTML 5 was introduced. You should try updating the the DOCTYPE to HTML 5 <!DOCTYPE html>

You should also do yourself a favour and update to at least a supported version of Visual Studio too.
